# ValueError: x and y must be the same size when try to draw the SVM

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, svm, scatter-plot

I am new at machine learning , I found python code to visulastion the result of SVM modle from sklearn in python
the code is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs

X,y=make_blobs(n_samples=40,centers=2,random_state=20)

clf=svm.SVC(kernel='linear',C=1000)
clf.fit(X,y)

plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c=y,s=30,cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

### assign new data
newData=[[3,4],[5,6]]

#print(clf.predict(newData))
#plot the deciston function
ax=plt.gca()
xlim=ax.get_xlim()
ylim=ax.get_ylim()

#creat a grid to evalute the modle
xx=np.linspace(xlim[0],xlim[1],30)
yy=np.linspace(ylim[0],ylim[1],30)
YY,XX=np.meshgrid(yy,xx)
xy=np.vstack([XX.ravel(),YY.ravel()]).T
Z=clf.decision_function(xy).reshape(XX.shape)

#plot decision bundray and margins
ax.contour(XX,YY,Z,colors='k',levels=[-1,0,1],alpha=0.5,linestyles=['--','-','--'])
# plot support vector
ax.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:0],clf.support_vectors_[:1],s=100,linewidths=1,facecolors='none')
plt.show()
```

when I run above code i got this error :

> File "C:/Users/Black_Swan/PycharmProjects/test/images/svm.py", line 47, in 
> ax.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:0],clf.support_vectors_[:1],s=100,linewidths=1,facecolors='none')
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 1870, in inner
> return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 4257, in scatter
> raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
> **ValueError: x and y must be the same size**

Can anyone help me find the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clf.support_vectors_` is a two dimensional array, so you need to do `clf.support_vectors_[:,0]` . Not very sure about your matplotlib version, I am on '3.4.1' so the below solution works for that version:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

X,y=make_blobs(n_samples=40,centers=2,random_state=20)

clf=svm.SVC(kernel='linear',C=1000)
clf.fit(X,y)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c=y,s=20,cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

newData=[[3,4],[5,6]]

ax=plt.gca()
xlim=ax.get_xlim()
ylim=ax.get_ylim()

#creat a grid to evalute the modle
xx=np.linspace(xlim[0],xlim[1],30)
yy=np.linspace(ylim[0],ylim[1],30)
YY,XX=np.meshgrid(yy,xx)
xy=np.vstack([XX.ravel(),YY.ravel()]).T
Z=clf.decision_function(xy).reshape(XX.shape)

ax.contour(XX,YY,Z,colors='k',levels=[-1,0,1],alpha=0.5,linestyles=['--','-','--'])
ax.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:,0],clf.support_vectors_[:,1],marker='o',
           edgecolors="black",s=90,c="None",linewidths=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`.scatter()` funciton takes float or array-like of `x` and `y` coordinates. As these are coordinates they are supposed to be in pairs and therefore `x` and `y` should be of equal length.
In your code `x` is `clf.support_vectors_[:0]` and `y` is `clf.support_vectors_[:1]`. The syntax `iterator[:k]` says that we should pick every element in the iterator until the k-th element which we should not pick.
So when we combine these things together we can spot that `x` and `y` have different lengths and therefore throw an error.